# Using \left( \right) in different lines in align environment

Tags: equations, align, line-breaking, brackets, right-to-left

I would like to produce an equation over two lines with a bracket opening in the first line and closing in the second line. Unfortunately, however, using the "\left" and "\right" commands (to have the size of the brackets automatically adjusted) leads to an error.

```
\begin{align*}
L &= \left[ \frac{a}{b} \\
&+ a \right]
\end{align*}
```

I would be very grateful for any advice on how to solve this problem! :)

Comment: Use `L &= \left[ \frac{a}{b} \right.` and `&\left.+ a \vphantom{\frac{a}{b}}\right]`. Alternatively use a specified size instead of auto-resizing.: `L &= \Bigl[ \frac{a}{b}` and `& + a  \Bigr]`.